# How to add websocket transport support for Thrift netstd .NET standard

Tags: thrift

How do I go about adding websocket client transport support to the c# .NET standard client library.

It looks like one should subclass the TStreamTransport type and call [System.Net.WebSockets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.websocket?view=netstandard-2.1) under the hood. Is that correct?

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

Short and simple: **Yes**.

If there are related questions, the [mailing list(s)](https://thrift.apache.org/mailing) may be a better fit for this kind of questions.